# RoR - make links clickable that show up in a user comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a Ruby script that takes a piece of text, and makes any links click-able that show up in it... Does anyone have something like this? For example, if I wrote  a comment and said "Come check out my site at http://www.example.com", then the link would be click-able like an html  tag.

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails has a View helper called `auto_link`, e.g.:

```
<%= auto_link("Please visit my site: http://www.example.org/") %>
```

would produce:

```
Please visit my site: <a href="http://www.example.org/">http://www.example.org/</a>
```

**Update:** You can find more information about it [here](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M005514).